# Active Directory LDS Structure Best Practices

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

I'm looking for guidance in structuring an LDS directory and finding only best practices targeted at Domain Services. Does anyone here have references for the hierarchical structure we set up in the directory?

I'm interested in small items, like whether to name the top node with "DC" tags or "O" tags, etc. E.g., should it be "DC=CompanyName,DC=local" when we're not actually using any specific domain? Shouldn't it be "O=CompanyName"? And I'm interested in whether this question is even worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use only DC tags for the root DN. For example:

```
DC=something,DC=example,DC=COM
```

I also match part of the root with the domain (in this case, it would be example.com). It is just a habit, it will not help or hinder your ability to use proxy accounts, for example.

Every LDAP enabled product I can think of allows you to specify the full DN of the path were your users are located. So the components you use don't matter as much as the structure itself (called the Directory Information Tree or DIT). You basically have to balance two things :

- A flat structure is future proof
- A deeply nested structure allows greater control (delegation, segregation of users)

A flat DIT, where for example all users would be under :

```
OU=Users,DC=something,DC=example,DC=COM
```

Will fit whatever organisational structure you have to work against. But you will sacrifice some ability to segregate users between applications using your LDS.

Here is an example. If you have two applications, you could have :

```
OU=Application_A,OU=Users,DC=something,DC=example,DC=COM
OU=Application_B,OU=Users,DC=something,DC=example,DC=COM
```

But what will happen if a user from `Application_A` wants to use `Application_B` ? Same goes for groups :

```
OU=Groups_A,OU=Users,DC=something,DC=example,DC=COM
OU=Groups_B,OU=Users,DC=something,DC=example,DC=COM
```

In short, don't worry about components, but give some thought about how well your DIT will fit in different reuse scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the difference between `dc=` and `o=` in Active Directory you need to remember that Active Directory is an [LDAP implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) at its core.

`DC=` in LDAP parlance specifies a ***Domain Component***. It should be used if *and only if* you are defining something that exists within the DNS space.
If your organization is `foobarco.example.com` in DNS it is perfectly legitimate to use `dc=foobarco,dc=example,dc=com` as your root.

`O=` in LDAP parlance specifies an ***Organization***. It should be used when defining an organizational item which exists outside of other hierarchies like DNS.
For example if `foobarco.example.com` had a subsidiary company called Shiny Widgets with its own AD domain, but not its own DNS domain, you would root that tree at `o=ShinyWidgets,dc=foobarco,dc=example,dc=com`.

---

Generally it is assumed that an AD Domain will have a corresponding DNS namespace, so the most common configuration you will see with Active Directory is that the tree root will be defined by a series of `D`omain `C`omponents.